# Inequality: $(a^3+a+1)(b^3+b+1)(c^3+c+1) \leq 27$

Tags: inequality

> Let be $a,b,c \geq 0$ such that: $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$.
>   Prove that: 
>   $$(a^3+a+1)(b^3+b+1)(c^3+c+1) \leq 27.$$

I try to apply $GM \leq AM$ for $x=a^3+a+1$, $y=b^3+b+1,z=c^3+c+1$ and 
$$\displaystyle \sqrt[3]{xyz} \leq \frac{x+y+z}{3}$$ but still nothing.

Thanks :-)

Comment: I don't know how to solve it, but maybe this can help yout:
$$
a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 3 => abc \le 1
$$

Comment: @daniel: $a=b=c=1$ is a solution.

Comment: One route to a solution would be to use the method of Lagrange multipliers to find the max of the function $(a^3+a+1)(b^3+b+1)(c^3+c+1)$ and to observe that of the $56$ (or so) possible candidates only $(1,1,1)$ has three positive coordinates.

Comment: It may be worth noting that $x^3 + x + 1 \leq 3$ for all $x \leq 1$.  If $a \geq b \geq c \geq 0$, then you need only worry about when $\sqrt{3} \geq a > 1$ (and hence $c < 1$).  I suppose this is the hardest one needs to handle here.

Comment: This inequality can be solved by noting that $x \to \ln(x^{3/2}+x^{1/2}+1)$ is concave for $x > 0$ and Jensen's inequality. Since dineshdileep noticed something similar first, I won't post this as answer. (Unless he doesn't edit his answer)

Comment: solutions without derivatives ?

Comment: @Iuli: It is not considered good form to make minor edits to your question simply to keep it on the front page. Note that after too many edits, your post will become Community Wiki, and you will stop getting reputation for it.

Comment: @Iuli: You may think about the substitution $a=\sqrt{3}\cos \alpha$, $b=\sqrt{3}\cos \beta$ and $c=\sqrt{3}\cos \gamma$ where $\cos^2 \alpha+ \cos^2 \beta+ \cos^2 \gamma=1$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Final solution :

http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=527572&p=2997801#p2997801

$$ (a-1)^4\geq0\Rightarrow a^3+a+1\leq\frac{(a^2+1)(a^2+5)}{4} $$

$$ \prod(a^3+a+1)\leq\frac{1}{64}\prod(a^2+1)\prod(a^2+5)$$

$$ \leq\frac{1}{64}\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2+3)^3}{27}\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2+15)^3}{27}=27 $$

Answer (score 15):

Let $u:=a^2, v:=b^2, w:=c^2$, we have $u+v+w=3$.
Consider the function
$$f(x)=\ln (1+x^{\frac{1}{2}}+x^{\frac{3}{2}}),\ 0<x\leq 3$$
it's easy to compute that $f''(x)<0$.
by Jensen's inequality, we have
$$\sum\ln (1+u^{\frac{1}{2}}+u^{\frac{3}{2}})\leq3f(\dfrac{\sum u}{3})=3\ln 3$$
that is
$$\prod(a^3+a+1) \leq 27$$
When the max occurs, we have $u=v=w\Rightarrow a=b=c$
Q.E.D.

By the way, I draw a graph of $f''(x)$ on $(0,3]$ by mathematica to show it more directly...
[image]

Comment: How do you know that the max occurs when $a=b=c$?

Comment: @Eckhard When the max occurs, we have $u=v=w\Rightarrow a=b=c$

Comment: How do you know that the max occurs when $u=v=w$?

Comment: @Eckhard Er... that is what Jensen's inequality indicates.

Comment: @ShaneChern, Are you sure? I don't think that Jensen's inequality tells you exactly what the equality cases are.

Comment: @Eckhard I've checked it in Hardy's *Inequalities, 2nd ed*, and that's exactly what the equality cases are as no interval are linear (see in §3.8).

Answer (score 6):

For what it's worth, this answer uses derivatives, but it does use a generally applicable method.

Since $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$, any variations, $(\delta a,\delta b,\delta c)$, of $(a,b,c)$ must satisfy
$$
a\,\delta a+b\,\delta b+c\,\delta c=0\tag{1}
$$
We are interested in finding the maximum of
$$
\log(a^3+a+1)+\log(b^3+b+1)+\log(c^3+c+1)\tag{2}
$$
At a critical point, the variations of $(2)$ must satisfy
$$
\frac{3a^2+1}{a^3+a+1}\delta a+\frac{3b^2+1}{b^3+b+1}\delta b+\frac{3c^2+1}{c^3+c+1}\delta c=0\tag{3}
$$
[Standard linearity arguments](http://www.whim.org/nebula/math/orthovar.html) say that if $(3)$ is true for all $(\delta a,\delta b,\delta c)$ that satisfy $(1)$, we have
$$
\left(\frac{3a^2+1}{a^3+a+1},\frac{3b^2+1}{b^3+b+1},\frac{3c^2+1}{c^3+c+1}\right)=k(a,b,c)\tag{4}
$$
That is,
$$
\frac{3a^2+1}{a^4+a^2+a}=\frac{3b^2+1}{b^4+b^2+b}=\frac{3c^2+1}{c^4+c^2+c}\tag{5}
$$
Note that
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{3x^2+1}{x^4+x^2+x}
=-\frac{6 x^5+4 x^3-3 x^2+2 x+1}{(x^4+x^2+x)^2}\tag{6}
$$
If $x\ge1$, then $6x^5+4x^3\ge3x^2$ and if $0\le x\le1$, then $2x+1\ge3x^2$. Therefore, for all $x\ge0$, $(6)$ is negative. That is,
$$
\frac{3x^2+1}{x^4+x^2+x}\tag{7}
$$
is monotonic decreasing which, when combined with $(5)$, says that
$$
a=b=c\tag{8}
$$
$(8)$ says that
$$
(a^3+a+1)(b^3+b+1)(c^3+c+1)=27\tag{9}
$$
Condition $(8)$ assumes that (a,b,c) is not on the boundary, that is none are $0$. Suppose that $c=0$, then the same argument yields that $a=b=\frac12\sqrt6$ and therefore
$$
(a^3+a+1)(b^3+b+1)(c^3+c+1)=\frac{83}{8}+\frac52\sqrt6\tag{10}
$$
Suppose that $b=c=0$, then $a=\sqrt3$ and therefore
$$
(a^3+a+1)(b^3+b+1)(c^3+c+1)=1+4\sqrt3\tag{11}
$$
Comparing $(9)$, $(10)$, and $(11)$, the maximum is $27$.

Comment: How is this different from Lagrange multiplier? This is just phrased in a tone-down way I suppose.

Comment: This is just an unrolled version of a Lagrange multiplier, as you say. I was pushing things to use derivatives, I didn't want to assume knowledge of Lagrange multipliers, too.

Answer (score 5):

General comment: as soon as one tries to use AM-GM for 
$x=a^3+a+1,$ $y=b^3+b+1$ and $z=c^3+c+1$ the inequality becomes wrong, since
$$a^3+a+b^3+b+c^3+c+3\ge 2(a^2+b^2+c^2)+3=9.$$
Using Lagrange multiplayers, one can reduce this problem to the following system:
$$(3a^2+1)(b^3+b+1)(c^3+c+1)=2\lambda a$$ 
$$(3b^2+1)(a^3+a+1)(c^3+c+1)=2\lambda b$$ 
$$(3c^2+1)(a^3+a+1)(b^3+b+1)=2\lambda c.$$

In other words, if $\lambda\ne 0,$ for the function
$$f(x)=\frac{x(x^3+x+1)}{(3x^2+1)}$$
 we have $f(a)=f(b)=f(c).$ It is easy to see, that $f$ is monotone for $x\ge 0$ so the only option is $a=b=c=1.$ The rest should be clear.

Comment: What is the easy way to see that $f$ is monotone for $x\ge0$? I took the derivative and was able to reason that its sign did not change. I would be interested in an easier method.

Comment: Well, what I had in mind was differentiation, which is quite easy in this particular case

Comment: So
$\displaystyle f'(x)=\frac{6 x^5+4 x^3-3 x^2+2 x+1}{\left(3 x^2+1\right)^2}\ge0$ by the same argument I used. Too bad.

Answer (score 3):

This will have derivatives. Substitute $a=\sqrt{x}, b=\sqrt{y}$ and $c=\sqrt{z}$. Then $x+y+z=3$. Consider the function $f(x)=\ln(x\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x}+1)$. It is concave.

Hence Jensen yields: $f(x)+f(y)+f(z)<=3f(1)=3\ln{3}$

This is equivalent to what is asked.

Comment: How is this different from the answer with 7 votes already?

Comment: It's not. I didn't pay enough attention.

Answer (score 3):

I have a new answer. We will apply the Cebysev's inequality.

$$(a^3+a+1)(b^3+b+1)\leq3(a^3b^3+ab+1)$$ 
So:

$$\left[(a^3+a+1)(b^3+b+1)(c^3+c+1)\right]^{2} \leq 27(a^3b^3+ab+1)(b^3c^3+cb+1)(c^3a^3+ac+1).$$

Now, we will prove that:

$$27(a^3b^3+ab+1)(b^3c^3+cb+1)(c^3a^3+ac+1) \leq 27^{2}.$$ Equivalent with:

$$(a^3b^3+ab+1)(b^3c^3+cb+1)(c^3a^3+ac+1) \leq 27.$$

Now we use $AM \geq GM$ :

$$(a^3b^3+ab+1)(b^3c^3+cb+1)(c^3a^3+ac+1) \leq \left(\frac{a^3b^3+b^3c^3+a^3c^3+ab+bc+ca+3}{3}\right)^{3}.$$

Now we will apply the following inequality to obtain the desired result:

$$a^3b^3+b^3c^3+a^3c^3 \leq \frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^{3}}{9}=3,$$
$$ab+bc+ca \leq a^2+b^2+c^2=3.$$

Comment: What Chebyshev inequality is this? If it's the similarly ordered sequence one, then why is $\{a^3,a,1\}$ and $\{b^3,b,1\}$ similarly ordered? In fact, they are not!

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to show that for $t\geqslant0$,
$$f(t) = \log(3)-\log\left(t^3+t+1\right)+\tfrac23\left(t^2-1\right)
\geqslant 0$$
as the inequality in question is merely $f(a)+f(b)+f(c)\geqslant0$.

But $f’(t)=0$ only when $t=1$ where it has a minimum, so $f(t)\geqslant f(1)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

**This is wrong**

If you are familiar with majorization, observe that the function is schur concave. Thus, its maximum occurs at a point where all variables are equal, and since that point exists in the constraint set (i.e. $a,b,c\geq 0$ and $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$), $a=b=c=1$ is the maxima. Thus, the inequality comes.

Comment: I think you mean it's Schur concave. Why is it true though?

Comment: It is symmetric and monotonically increasing in each argument.

Comment: sorry, i meant it is schur-concave. Thanks for the help

Comment: How does monotonically increasing imply concavity? When one vector majorizes another, it's possible that some components are larger, while some components are smaller.

Comment: my intuition was that the function is symmetric, and also it is convex in each variable. Therefore, it should be schur-convex, but now it seems schur-concave is what we needed. I don't know how to correct it, it all seemed to fit well. !!

Comment: Product of convex functions may not be convex. In fact LHS is neither convex or concave on $[0,3]$. I'm not sure about Schur-convexity/concavity, but I don't think it's something you can handwave.

Comment: In fact, no, it can't be Schur-convex/concave, because $log(x^3+x+1)$ is neither convex or concave. This means that one can cook up counterexamples by picking points in the region where the function is convex then picking points where the function is concave.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7200/discussion-between-dineshdileep-and-sanchez)

Comment: my bad! I should have done a change of variable. In fact $x \to \log(x^{3/2}+x^{1/2}+1)$ is concave on $x > 0$. I am not familiar with the terminology of Schur concavity, but usual Jensen's inequality would work.

Comment: so, what is the conclusion?

Comment: See Shane Chern's answer.

Comment: So does it mean the function is schur-concave after all?

Comment: $(a,b,c) \to (a^3+a+1)(b^3+b+1)(c^3+c+1)$, no. $(u,v,w) \to (u^{3/2}+u^{1/2}+1)(v^{3/2}+v^{1/2}+1)(w^{3/2}+w^{1/2}+1)$, yes.