# Prove that $\prod \limits_{cyc}(a^3+a+1 ) \leq 27$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

> Let $a,b,c > 0$ such that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 =3$. Prove that
>
> $$(a^3+a+1)(b^3+b+1)(c^3+c+1) \leq 27$$

My attempt :

Let $\lambda = \prod \limits_{cyc} a^3+a+1$ .

Applying AM-GM on the set $\{(a^3+a+1),(b^3+b+1),(c^3+c+1)\}$ :

$$\lambda^{\frac{1}{3}}\leq\dfrac{\sum \limits_{cyc} a^3+a^2+a}{3} \leq \dfrac{\sum \limits_{cyc} a^3 +2a^2 }{3} = 2+\dfrac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3}$$

I am struck now and do not how to proceed. The question seems easy but I can not figure out the right strategy. Also, C-S does not seem to help.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: I've read this somewhere before (which is why the proof has no context). Beats me where the source was.

Comment: @S.C.B. It is actually a problem from AoPS....

Comment: Really? I think I saw it somewhere else.

Comment: Here is the [link](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t321f6h517578_inequality__from_gazeta_matematica)

Comment: So do you understand my answer?

Comment: There are other AoPS questions with the same idea.

Comment: For example, @Nirbhay see [here](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h511786p2873589).

Comment: Why the downvotes ?

Comment: Just try to ignore them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inequality: $(a^3+a+1)(b^3+b+1)(c^3+c+1) \leq 27$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283895/inequality-a3a1b3b1c3c1-leq-27)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the expansion of $a^4-4a^3+6a^2-4a+1=(a-1)^{4} \ge 0$, we can simply the equation to get the following: $$4a^3+4a+4 \le a^4+6a^2+5 $$

So we have that 
$$\prod_{cyc}(a^3+a+1)\leq\frac{1}{4^3}\prod_{cyc}(a^2+1)\prod_{cyc}(a^2+5) \le 27$$
From $\text{AM-GM}$ Inequality. We have the desired result.